# QGIS options menu causes freeze on Ubuntu 16.04, solutions?

Tags: qgis, ubuntu

First time asking, I've checked the internet and no luck.  I am unable to edit the program options in QGIS 2.14.3 running on Ubuntu 16.04 (settings -> options).  I've uninstalled all QGIS packages (via purge) and reinstalled, yet the issue still persists.  Regular QGIS operation works, although slow, hence why I need to edit default settings (multipoint shapefile of only a couple megabytes won't render properly).  Does anyone have suggestions for how to do a proper full uninstall and reinstall, or ideas for underlying non-QGIS libraries that could be causing the issue?  Does not appear to be a documented issue online.  The issue persists even when no project is loaded.  QGIS CPU usage goes to 100% and the program has to be killed from command line.

This is the output on the command line both with and without sudo :

```
~$ sudo qgis 
Warning: loading of qgis translation failed [/usr/share/qgis/i18n//qgis_en_US]
Warning: loading of qt translation failed [/usr/share/qt4/translations/qt_en_US]
Warning: QCss::Parser - Failed to load file  "/style.qss" 
^C^C^\

~$ qgis
Warning: loading of qgis translation failed [/usr/share/qgis/i18n//qgis_en_US]
Warning: loading of qt translation failed [/usr/share/qt4/translations/qt_en_US]
Warning: QCss::Parser - Failed to load file  "/style.qss" 
Warning: QVariantMap DBusMenuExporterDBus::getProperties(int, const QStringList&) const: Condition failed: action 
Warning: QVariantMap DBusMenuExporterDBus::getProperties(int, const QStringList&) const: Condition failed: action 
Warning: void DBusMenuExporterPrivate::addAction(QAction*, int): Already tracking action "Terms of Service / About" under id 259 
Warning: void DBusMenuExporterPrivate::addAction(QAction*, int): Already tracking action "&Toolbox" under id 366 
Warning: void DBusMenuExporterPrivate::fillLayoutItem(DBusMenuLayoutItem*, QMenu*, int, int, const QStringList&): No id for action 
Warning: void DBusMenuExporterPrivate::fillLayoutItem(DBusMenuLayoutItem*, QMenu*, int, int, const QStringList&): No id for action 
^C^\Quit (core dumped)
```

Comment: Works for me with QGIS 2.14.1 on Xenial. though it would not let me upgrade to 2.14.3. I suggest to wait for QGIS 2.16 which is just around the corner.

Comment: This would be more suitable at https://hub.qgis.org/issues/ ! For now, you could try removing ~/.qgis2/ which is the directory where user settings are stored. Never run QGIS as root, there is no reason to do so! I would suggest you also purge /root/.qgis2/

Comment: thanks!  didn't know about the .qgis2.  if that doesn't fix it i'll submit the issue.  waiting on next version also reasonable.  it's not a crippling issue.